# JavaScript - Only the first part of if statement gets evaluated

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, conditional-statements

In my code I'm looping over an array of Twitch.tv usernames(called users) to make an API call with each of them. The code for that looks like this:

```
for(user in users){
  var username = users[user];
  console.log(username); //it iterates over every user in the array
  cbJSON(username); //that means this function is called for each user
}
```

The cbJSON function takes one argument, the username, and makes an API call. Then it should write to the console if the user is online, offline or doesn't exist. For that I'm using an if statement that evaluates if data.stream is true, null, or undefined like this:

```
function cbJSON(name){
  $.getJSON(url + name + cb, function(data){
  var ds = data.stream;

  //Problem: Only the initial if statement works.
  //The else if and else statements are NEVER called

  //Only this works
  if(ds){
    //handle user is online
      //show status, name, game, viewers, resolution

    console.log(name + ' is online.');

    //this is never called, even though it should be
  } else if(ds === null) {
    //handle user is offline
      //show status, logo and name
    console.log(name + ' is offline.');

    //this is never called, even though it should be
  } else {
    //handle user does not exist
      //error message: user does not exist
    console.log(name + ' does not exist.');
  }
  });
}
```

ds should evaluate to true whenever data.stream exists and isn't falsy.
ds equals null when the stream is offline.
ds equals undefined when the channel doesn't exist.

Only the first part if this if statement seems to get evaluated. If someone in the users array is online, 'username is online' gets written to the console. However, most users in the array are offline and one doesn't exist, so those should also get written to the console as 'username is offline' and 'username does not exist'.

This is a rather simple if statement, and I didn't think I'd run into any trouble here, but I can't figure out why this isn't working as expected. I'm just gonna link my codepen here, because it is possible that the problem lies somewhere else: http://codepen.io/erody-s/pen/WwagBo?editors=1011

One more thing: The if statement was working yesterday, but I changed a bunch of stuff since then, including how the cbJSON function is called, and it has since stopped working properly.

I'm still somewhat new to JavaScript, so it's likely that I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't figure it out on my own. Believe me, I've tried.

I would be very glad if anyone was able to help me on this.

Comment: Why don't you `console.log` the value of `ds`. If the first conditional is always executing you can bet that `ds` is always truthy. Also - what is data.stream? Is there an API doc for this response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug.

You do a bunch of assignments after assigning ds

```
var ds = data.stream;
var linkStream = ds.channel.url;
var logo = ds.channel.logo;
var displayName = ds.channel.display_name;
var game = ds.game;
var viewers = ds.viewers;
var resolution = ds.video_height;
var preview = ds.preview.small;
```

You also said that when the streamer is offline ds should be null right? Well, in Javascript, if you try to get a property of a null or undefined variable you'll throw an error and the rest of the function will not be executed.
So, I fixed your pen for you: http://codepen.io/josepht404/pen/RaqbRw?editors=1012 it works now :).

I hope I helped, thanks.

Comment: I did, don't have enough reputation yet for it to show though

Answer (score -1):

```
function cbJSON(name){
  $.getJSON(url + name + cb, function(data){
  var ds = data.stream;
     console.log(ds); //
  });
}
```

`ds` is an object it will always be truthy. You need to find the property on `ds` that can be evaluated for the user's online/offline status.

```
Object:
{
   _id:21070202752,
   _links:Object,
   average_fps:60,
   channel:Object,
   created_at:"2016-04-30T08:02:01Z",
   delay:0,
   game:"Minecraft",
   is_playlist:false,
   preview:Object,
   video_height:698,
   viewers:299,
   __proto__:Object
 }
```

This is the `ds` object.

Comment: That's inherently not true, ds is not always true. Check the Pen.

Comment: I see it as true? what does ds look like on the console when not true?

Comment: It's either null or undefined

Comment: As of now, I only have one user with a truthy ds